# Using Grunt Property Expand for creating appropriate page-based above the fold css

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

My goal is to create an appropriate above the fold `.css` file for each appropriate `.html` page.

I'm using [grunt-penthouse](https://github.com/fatso83/grunt-penthouse) to extract the css and it works fine.. as long as you have only **one** `html` page. my current configuration goes something like this:

```
penthouse: {
    extract: {
        outfile: '_dev/critical-css/index.css',
        css: '_dev/css/main.css',
        url: '_dev/index.html',
        width: 1200,
        height: 500
    },
},
```

what I want to avoid is transforming my gruntfile into something like this:

```
penthouse: {
    index: {
        outfile: '_dev/critical-css/index.css',
        css: '_dev/css/main.css',
        url: '_dev/index.html',
        width: 1200,
        height: 500
    },
    contact: {
        outfile: '_dev/critical-css/contact.css',
        css: '_dev/css/main.css',
        url: '_dev/contact.html',
        width: 1200,
        height: 500
    },
    blog: {
        outfile: '_dev/critical-css/blog.css',
        css: '_dev/css/main.css',
        url: '_dev/blog.html',
        width: 1200,
        height: 500
    },
// and so on
},
```

I've been reading about [grunt expand property](https://oncletom.io/2013/dynamic-grunt-targets-using-templates/) and grunt templating and I feel like I'm on the right path. I guess I need a syntax that looks like something like this:

```
expand: true,
cwd: '_src/',
src: ['**/<%= filename =%>.html'],
dest: '_dev/critical-css/',
ext: '<%= filename =%>.css'
```

but I sincerly don't know where to start from and if I'm effectively on the right path.

I'd like that, anytime I modify an `.html` page, penthouse triggers and spits the right above the fold `.css` file with the right filename for that specific page.

if you want more context, I want to implement this in this workflow i'm creating: https://github.com/vlrprbttst/grunt-boilerplate-v2

any help or even a simple heads up is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this to generate dynamically your **Gruntfile** task. 
You should define:

1. **destFolder**: the folder to extract filenames from
2. **fileExt**: the extension for files you need to extrapolate.

The code checks for files in the folder, and clean their url to get only the page name without extension. It is all possible thanks to the grunt.file.expand method. You could supply a lot of options, but I will pass an empty object because in this particular case they are not useful. You can find more informations in the [grunt.file docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand).

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var destFolder = "pages/";
    var fileExt = ".html";

    var options = {}; 

    var tempFileList = grunt.file.expand(
        { options },
        [ destFolder + "*" + fileExt ] // structure to analyse
    );

    // I create an empty array to put all elements in, once cleaned. 
    var fileList = [];

    tempFileList.forEach(function(url){
        var pageUrl = url;
        // remove the destination folder
        pageUrl = pageUrl.replace(destFolder, "");
        // remove file extension
        pageUrl = pageUrl.replace(fileExt, "");
        fileList.push(pageUrl);
    })

    var min = {};
    fileList.forEach(function(name) {
        min[name] = {
            outfile: '_dev/critical-css/'+name+'.css',
            css: '_dev/css/main.css',
            url: '_dev/'+name+'.html',
            width: 1200,
            height: 500
        };
    });

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        penthouse: min
    });

};
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use template strings in your configuration object if you're looking to minimize repetitive task targets:

```
penthouse: {
    extract: {
        outfile: "_dev/critical-css/<%= grunt.option('fileName') %>.css",
        css: '_dev/css/main.css',
        url: "_dev/<%= grunt.option('fileName') %>.html",
        width: 1200,
        height: 500
    },
}
```

Next, you'll need to write to write a function.  Its purpose: Get the list of files to process, iterate through each file, assigning the filename to the template string and running the task for the specified file.

```
function extractCSS() {
    var fileName,
        files = [];

    // For each file that matches the glob pattern, get the file name
    grunt.file.expand('_dev/*.html').forEach(function (filePath) {
        files.push(filePath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0]);
    });

    for (fileName in files) {
        grunt.option('fileName', fileName);
        grunt.task.run('penthouse:extract');
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('extract-css', extractCSS);
```

Comment: Nice! Would it work with the `grunt.option` and `grunt.task.run` calls inside `forEach`?  This way, you don't have to instantiate `fineName` and `files`.

Comment: You would need to modify the task to run asynchronously, but I wouldn't recommend it - it's plausible that between setting the grunt option to `foo` and running the processing task, another instance could set the grunt option to `bar`.  The result would be your `foo` output having your `bar` data.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered generating the config object by iterating over an array?  It's quick-and-easy, for your use-case.

```
var confTargets = ['index', 'contact', 'blog']
penthouse = {};

for (var i = 0; i < confTargets.length; i++) {
    var target = confTargets[i];
    penthouse[target] = {
        outfile: '_dev/critical-css/' + target + '.css',
        css: '_dev/css/main.css',
        url: '_dev/' + target + '.html',
        width: 1200,
        height: 500
    }
}
```

Comment: does this works in a gruntfile? that could be a solution, what I strongly wanted to avoid is having to list my pages. I want to know if there's a way of extracting the css file from the system file name instead of listing them in an array

Comment: It should work if you make the object before defining the task.  But yeah, you'll have to add an item to the array when you add a page.

Comment: You could also use `fs.readdir` to grab the list of file names....but then again, it seems like grunt should be able to do that.

Comment: This solution does not take the grunt framework into account at all